# Split plain text from img tag using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a api response that is a combination of plain text and image tag. What is the best way to separate plain text from the response? I need to separate plain text so I can style it separately.

This is the example of a response:

```
This is the cap you unscrew to open when you refuel your car <img alt="blah" src="https://www.lifesure.co.uk/cms/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Tyre-Illustration-500.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to remove html tag like this

```
str = str.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
```

or you this if only remove image tag `str = str.replace(/<img .*?>/g, '');`

```js
var str = 'This is the cap you unscrew to open when you refuel your car <img alt="blah" src="https://www.lifesure.co.uk/cms/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Tyre-Illustration-500.jpg" />'
//str = str.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
str = str.replace(/<img .*?>/g, '');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to use the following regular expression `/<img[\s\w=\":/.-]+>/gmi` to match and replace the `<img />` tag in your response string:

```js
const responseText = `This is the cap you unscrew to open when you refuel your car <img alt="blah" src="https://www.lifesure.co.uk/cms/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Tyre-Illustration-500.jpg" />`

const responseWithoutImageTag = responseText.replace(/<img[\s\w=\":/.-]+>/gmi, '')

console.log(responseWithoutImageTag)
```

Answer (score 0):

[A safer way than regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1958726) is to parse the HTML and extract the text content:

```
var template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = 'This is the cap you unscrew to open when you refuel your car <img alt="blah" src="https://www.lifesure.co.uk/cms/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Tyre-Illustration-500.jpg" />';
```

`template.content.textContent` returns `'This is the cap you unscrew to open when you refuel your car '`

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to go, but `.textContent` doesn't help with this part of the requirement: _"I need to separate plain text **so I can style it separately**"_

Comment: @Andreas True, but the gist of the question is how to separate them since how the style is applied depends on the method of rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring from o to index of image tag

```js
    var str = 'This is the cap you unscrew to open when you refuel your car <img alt="blah" src="https://www.lifesure.co.uk/cms/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Tyre-Illustration-500.jpg" />'

var newStr = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('<img'));
console.log(newStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you could do this:

```
const textOnly = str.slice(0, str.indexOf('<img'));
```

If you want the image tag only:

```
const imageTag = str.slice(str.indexOf('<img'), str.length);
```

(substring works too, like in the answer by Syed)